# OOP Javascript, get instance name

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an object and I write the instance:

```
var table1=new searchTable(someoptions)
```

Is there anyway to get "table1" programatically from inside the object?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Objects have no knowledge of what variables and properties (there can be multiple) they are assigned to.

Answer (score 3):

*There is absolutely no way of doing this.*

When you do

```
LHS = RHS
```

`RHS` has no clue of what its result is going to be assigned to.